# Stanford ner tagger is case sensitive

Tags: python-2.7, stanford-nlp

Recently i started exploring stanford ner tagger through nltk. we are trying to create our own customize model for NER. I observed that Stanford ner is behaving different for different case

I am using python 2.7 , using stanford-ner-2018-02-27.zip. The model used is english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz.

from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordNERTagger
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

st = StanfordNERTagger('/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz',                       '
/stanford-ner.jar',
                       encoding='utf-8')

tokenized_text = word_tokenize(text)
nertag_text = st.tag(tokenized_text)

example -

text = 'While in France, Christine Lagarde discussed short-term stimulus efforts in a recent interview with the Wall Street Journal.'

the tag result

[(u'While', u'O'), (u'in', u'O'), (u'France', u'LOCATION'), (u',', u'O'), (u'Christine', u'PERSON'), (u'Lagarde', u'PERSON'), (u'discussed', u'O'), (u'short-term', u'O'), (u'stimulus', u'O'), (u'efforts', u'O'), (u'in', u'O'), (u'a', u'O'), (u'recent', u'O'), (u'interview', u'O'), (u'with', u'O'), (u'the', u'O'), (u'Wall', u'ORGANIZATION'), (u'Street', u'ORGANIZATION'), (u'Journal', u'ORGANIZATION'), (u'.', u'O')]

While making the text to lowercase

text="while in france, christine lagarde discussed short-term stimulus efforts in a recent interview with the wall street journal"

tag result

[(u'while', u'O'), (u'in', u'O'), (u'france', u'O'), (u',', u'O'), (u'christine', u'PERSON'), (u'lagarde', u'PERSON'), (u'discussed', u'O'), (u'short-term', u'O'), (u'stimulus', u'O'), (u'efforts', u'O'), (u'in', u'O'), (u'a', u'O'), (u'recent', u'O'), (u'interview', u'O'), (u'with', u'O'), (u'the', u'O'), (u'wall', u'O'), (u'street', u'O'), (u'journal', u'O')]

There is difference in tag values. Is there any stanford ner model which ignore case sensitive.